# How to implement BottomNavigation with 5 item and one of them has a profile activity with tablayout?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout, bottomnavigationview

I am working on app in which I have bottom navigation with 5 item. and I created 5 fragment for each of them. Everything is working right till now. But there is problem in what I want to make in profile fragment. In profile fragment I implemented collapsing tool bar with tablayout. everything works fine except i open profile fragment and then any other fragment and after that when I click again on profile fragment the content of tablayout is not showing. it shows when I click on left and right tab of tab layout but center tab content is not showing.

[image: When I open the app]

[image: When I click on Profile]

[image: When I click middle tab(Resume)]

I made same layout in all tab for testing purpose

[image: When I click on notification]

[image: When I click on profile again]

[image: when I tab on profile in tab layout]

[image: when tab on activity in tab layout]

[image: When I tab on profile again in tablayout]

this is the problem I lost the content of accountfragment once I click on any other fragment through bottom navigation.

the content is back in profile tab and activity tab after first changing but the content of resume is not getting back.

Comment: Please check all the images one by one

Answer (score 0):

As you have not shared your code, i cannot pin-point to the problem, but if you want you can view this video about implementing Bottom Navigation View.

[Bottom Navigation View](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oeKtwd1DBfg)